# When will Java SE 7 release?

Tags: java, api

I was just curious to know when will Java se 7 release and what will be the major things added to it...
Is this the [final API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)?
Should i make this question community wiki?

Comment: This isn't really answerable, is it?

Comment: I think, OP want's to know if there's already a release date or plan for Java 7. That would be answerable. (My guess: there isn't one, but I don't know).

Comment: @Tom: This question is not as "dumb" as you might think. Not everyone is up to date on Oracle's plans and Java's status. The answer to the question is: Nobody knows, a release date for Java SE 7 has not been announced.

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 2):

As with most things, I believe Java 7 will be released simply 'when it is ready'. Here is a link to the milestones for the project: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/milestones/. Here is are the associated dates with the milestones: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/calendar/.

I can't imagine that the API is finalized yet. The link your provided, for example, clearly states that it is a draft API. Also, according to the milestones and the calendar there is still work to be done.

Answer (score 0):

It will release when Oracle decides to release it.  Not a minute sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 has not officially been released so that is not the final API. This page has some info of what may or may not be coming in java 7... http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/